# Regular expression boundary matchers for beginning of line (^) and end of line ($) not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern using ^ and $ to indicate beginning and end of line.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "^Key2 = (.+)$" );
```

and input like this:

```
String text = "Key1 = Twas brillig, and the slithy toves"
  + "\nKey2 = Did gyre and gimble in the wabe."
  + "\nKey3 = All mimsy were the borogroves."
  + "\nKey4 = And the mome raths outgrabe.";
```

But `pattern.matcher( text ).find()` returns `false`.

Shouldn't this work? In the [Pattern class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the summary specifies:

```
Boundary matchers
^  The beginning of a line
$  The end of a line
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, those symbols match the beginning and end of the *entire input sequence*.

Further down in that [same Pattern class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (with emphasis added):

> By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the *entire input sequence.* If MULTILINE mode is activated then ^ matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input. When in MULTILINE mode $ matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence.

So you can make ^ and $ work as they are documented in summary table by compiling the pattern with `Pattern.MULTILINE`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "^Key2 = (.+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE );
```

Comment: fantastic :) i have struggled with this myself in the past

Comment: @AbtPst - Myself as well. The details in the javadoc are buried; the summary could use a brief clarification. I've encountered, solved, and forgotten this multiple times over the years. Next time there will be this stackoverflow question!